# What is the correct name of this 'basis label operator'?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology

What is the correct name for this operator I am calling the 'basis label operator' which returns the constant function of the eigenvalue for all vectors in a (momentum) eigenspace?

$$\hat{O} : \hat{O}(\psi) \rightarrow \frac{-i\hbar}{\psi}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}$$

for those who would like me to be a little more formal / explicit in my formulation, I could write exactly the same definition as:

$$\hat{O} : \hat{O}(\psi) \rightarrow \left( \phi: \phi(a) \rightarrow \left. \frac{-i\hbar}{\psi(a)}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \right \rvert_{x=a}\right)$$

Comment: Assuming it’s extended to all vectors by linearity, this is the expectation value of momentum.

Comment: Hi @knzhou Is there a theorem that this will give the expectation value of momentum for non-eigenfunctions? I wouldn't have expected that because I don't think it is a linear operator. I'm not sure what you meant by "extended to all vectors by linearity" but I think this operator is defined for all states in the Hilbert space without being linear.

Comment: This is a very unusual object, in what context would this come up? I don't think that it has a name.

Comment: @user183966 Sorry, I shouldn't have said "extended by linearity" because it's not linear.

Comment: It's not a linear operator, so it's a bit confusing to call it an "operator" in the quantum mechnical sense.

Comment: Point is, if you define "division by $\psi$" to mean projection onto $|\psi \rangle$, your operator maps $|\psi \rangle$ to $\langle \psi | \hat{p} |\psi \rangle$, so by definition it's the expectation value of momentum. If that's not what you mean by dividing by $\psi$, then the operation is likely meaningless.

Comment: I assume $\hat O$ is supposed to give $\frac{-i\hbar}{\psi(x)} \frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x}$ in position space.

Comment: @Noiralef yes thank you this is correct. I am actually interested in a more general or abstract family of operators as you might have guessed but I am trying to make it as concrete as possible to make it clear and easy to answer. I am also trying to make the notation terse enough to show what I am interested in. I could make it completely formal but I think that would obscure the question.

Comment: @knzhou by division by $\psi$ I mean division by the value of $\psi$ at that point.

Comment: @mikestone it is not an observable; I agree however I thought calling it a "function" would be even more confusing and wasn't sure what else I should call it to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: What happens when $\psi(x)=0$?

Comment: @J.Murray I don't think that is a member of the Hilbert space. So I think I would say for this question that it is undefined.

Comment: @J.Murray Sorry just realised what you meant $\psi(x)$ not $\psi$. That is a very interesting question. Not sure, maybe it would have to be over distributions rather than functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps that
$$ \hat O = \hat p \circ \log_x $$
where $\log_x$ is defined by its action in position space:
$$ \log_x( |\psi\rangle ) = \int |x'\rangle\, \log(\langle x' | \psi \rangle)\, \mathrm dx' . $$

**However.** Be warned that, if something like this comes up in your calculations, and you are not 100% sure what you are doing, I think it is likely that what you are doing does not make sense at all. Non-linear operators come up only very rarely. Also note that I was careful in specifying that the action of the operator depends on the position space representation of $|\psi\rangle$. It is very unnatural to consider an operator whose action depends on a specific representation of the Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely interesting. I am exploring auxiliary tools/formulations for quantum mechanics that do not rely on linear operators. As you know normal observable operators multiply each eigencomponent by it's 'labelled' value. I was considering operators that return the value instead of multiplying by the value (so as to use a 'traditional property' language rather than a linear operator language.) I know the expectation value also has that characteristic but I rarely see this expressed explicitly a an operator.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform this made the answer clearer to me